# Aligned Line Dash Patterns in 2 CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm calling to you Core Animation Gods! I'm trying to display a shape in iOS. The idea is to draw a square with dashed strokes, inner and outer, like shown in the following image created with the Sketch app.

[image: square shape with two dashed borders created in sketch]

I'm implementing it creating three layers, one for the outer stroke, one for the inner, and one for the fill. Here is my code:

```swift
        // setup square properties
        let lineDashPattern = [10, 5]
            .map({ NSNumber(value: $0) })
        let strokeWidth = CGFloat(5)
        let frame = CGRect(
            x: 40,
            y: 40,
            width: 119,
            height: 119)
        let pathBox = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: frame.size.width,
            height: frame.size.width)

        // Create the container layer
        let square = CALayer()
        square.frame = frame

        // create the fill
        let fill = CAShapeLayer()
        fill.frame = pathBox
        fill.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        fill.path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame).cgPath

        // Creater the inner border
        let innerBorder = CAShapeLayer()
        innerBorder.frame = frame
        innerBorder.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        innerBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        innerBorder.lineDashPattern = lineDashPattern
        innerBorder.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        innerBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: pathBox)
            .cgPath
            .contract(by: strokeWidth / 2)

        // Create the outer border
        let outerBorder = CAShapeLayer()
        outerBorder.frame = frame
        outerBorder.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        outerBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        outerBorder.lineDashPattern = lineDashPattern
        outerBorder.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        outerBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: pathBox)
            .cgPath
            .contract(by: -(strokeWidth / 2))

        // add all to screen
        square.addSublayer(fill)
        square.addSublayer(innerBorder)
        square.addSublayer(outerBorder)
        view.layer.addSublayer(square)
```

I also created the following extensions on CGPath to facilitate scaling the path of the shape to create the strokes:

```swift
extension CGPath {
    func contract(by value: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        let finalBoundingBox = boundingBox.insetBy(
            dx: value,
            dy: value)
        let scaleFactor: CGFloat = finalBoundingBox.width / boundingBox.width

        var scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .centerScaledBy(x: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor, bounds: boundingBox)

        return copy(using: &scaleTransform)!
    }

}

extension CGAffineTransform {

    func centerScaledBy(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, bounds: CGRect) -> CGAffineTransform {
        let center = bounds.center
        var xform  = self

        xform = xform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -center.x, y: -center.y))
        xform = xform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: x, y: y))
        xform = xform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: center.x, y: center.y))

        return xform
    }
}

extension CGRect {

    var center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.midX, y: midY)
    }
}
```

However, the result is different, I get completely misaligned stroke dashes like:

[image: square shape with two dashed borders created in with core animation]

I guess that Sketch uses Core Animation layers under the hood, so whatever can be accomplished with sketch should also be reproducible by code, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best to ask the graphic artist how she did it, and use the same method. It might a single layer for both dashed lines, and then some filter that overlays the gray rectangle over it and causes the inner dashes to change color.

Comment: Nah, actually in Sketch you can create a shape with multiple borders and fills. So he added two borders with dashed line for the same shape, one inside and one outside. But CAShapeLayer only supports one border per layer, that’s why I thought of reproducing it using multiple layers

Comment: @Yonat I updated the first screenshot to better illustrate how the design was created

Answer (score 0):

The dashes in the Sketch app example don't look like normal dashes – notice that the lengths of the dash segments in the corners are non-uniform. To recreate this I'd just use eight separate layers: four for the four inner edges and then another four layers for the outer edges. I'd play with [lineDashPhase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521856-linedashphase) to make the dash patterns on the outer edges match the inner ones.

Comment: Yeah, but that would only work for squares. What if the shape is more complex? like some crazy curves. I'm looking for a solution that would work for any shape.